# preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to use `preg_match()` such that there should not be special characters such as ``@#$%^&/ '` in a given string.

For example :

`Coding` : Outputs valid
: Outputs Invalid(String beginning with space)
`Project management` :Outputs valid (space between two words are valid)
'Design23' :Outputs valid
`23Designing` : outputs invalid
`123` :Outputs invalid

I tried but could not reach to a valid answer.

Comment: This smells like homework. If it is please tag it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
'/^[a-zA-Z][\w ]+$/'
```

Comment: Thanks i got the result and the logic too

Answer (score 2):

Does a regex like this help?

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]\w*$`

It means:

- `^` = this pattern must start from the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` = this char can be any letter (`a-z` and `A-Z`) or digit (`0-9`, also see `\d`)
- `\w` = A word character. This includes letters, numbers and white-space (not new-lines by default)
- `*` = Repeat thing 0 or more times
- `$` = this pattern must finish at the end of the string

To satisfy the condition I missed, try this

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*$`

The extra stuff I added lets it have a digit for the first character, but it must always contain a letter because of the `[a-zA-Z]+` since `+` means 1 or more.

Comment: Of course, there is probably a better way to do this and the standard "I have not tested this" disclaimer applies

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework, you maybe should just learn regular expressions:

- [Regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [Regular expressions reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- [PCRE syntax reference for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)